# ansible synchronize module fails to get directory from remote to local - failed: No such file or directory

Tags: ansible, rsync, synchronized, nosuchfileexception, filenotfounderror

I wish to copy `/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopyprod` from `mysourceuser@mysourcehost` to destination `mydestuser@mydesthost` under the below location `/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopy/tmpfiles/500/`

Evident that both the source and destinations are present and have good permissions.

```
[mydestuser@mydesthost ~]$ ssh mysourceuser@mysourcehost ls -ld '/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopyprod'

##################################################################
# *** This Server is using Centrify                          *** #
# *** Remember to use your Active Directory account          *** #
# ***    password when logging in                            *** #
##################################################################

drwxrwxr-x 3 mysourceuser mysourceuser 209 Sep 26 14:58 /web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopyprod
[mydestuser@mydesthost ~]$ ls -ld /web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopy/tmpfiles/500/
drwxr-xr-x 2 mydestuser aces 6 Sep 26 14:13 /web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopy/tmpfiles/500/
```

Here is my playbook that runs on the `mydesthost` and gets me files & folders from a remote server `mysourceuser@mysourcehost` to local server `mydestuser@mydesthost`

```
   - name: Copying from "{{ inventory_hostname }}" to this ansible server.
     tags: validate
     synchronize:
       src: "'{{ item }}'"
       dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tmpfiles/{{ Latest_Build_Number }}/"
       mode: pull
       copy_links: yes
     with_items:
       - "{{ source_file_new.splitlines() }}"
```

To run the above playbook:

```
ansible-playbook /web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopy/copyfiles.yml -e "source_file_new='$source_file_new'" -e "Latest_Build_Number='500'"
```

Output of my run:

```
TASK [Copying from "mysourcehost" to this ansible server.] **********************
task path: /web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopy/copyfiles.yml:218
Monday 26 September 2022  14:13:02 -0500 (0:00:00.047)       0:00:03.084 ****** 
redirecting (type: action) ansible.builtin.synchronize to ansible.posix.synchronize
redirecting (type: action) ansible.builtin.synchronize to ansible.posix.synchronize
<mysourcehost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: mydestuser
<mysourcehost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/mydestuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-20463qmilic81 `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/mydestuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-20463qmilic81/ansible-tmp-1664219583.0005133-20679-105296975361597 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1664219583.0005133-20679-105296975361597="` echo /home/mydestuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-20463qmilic81/ansible-tmp-1664219583.0005133-20679-105296975361597 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /home/mydestuser/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/posix/plugins/modules/synchronize.py
<mysourcehost> PUT /home/mydestuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-20463qmilic81/tmpxhpyaf0m TO /home/mydestuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-20463qmilic81/ansible-tmp-1664219583.0005133-20679-105296975361597/AnsiballZ_synchronize.py
<mysourcehost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/mydestuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-20463qmilic81/ansible-tmp-1664219583.0005133-20679-105296975361597/ /home/mydestuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-20463qmilic81/ansible-tmp-1664219583.0005133-20679-105296975361597/AnsiballZ_synchronize.py && sleep 0'
<mysourcehost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /home/mydestuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-20463qmilic81/ansible-tmp-1664219583.0005133-20679-105296975361597/AnsiballZ_synchronize.py && sleep 0'
<mysourcehost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/mydestuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-20463qmilic81/ansible-tmp-1664219583.0005133-20679-105296975361597/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
failed: [mysourcehost] (item=/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopyprod) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --copy-links --archive --rsh=/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L mysourceuser@mysourcehost:'/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopyprod' /web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopy/tmpfiles/500/",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_local_rsync_password": null,
            "_local_rsync_path": "rsync",
            "_substitute_controller": false,
            "archive": true,
            "checksum": false,
            "compress": true,
            "copy_links": true,
            "delete": false,
            "dest": "/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopy/tmpfiles/500/",
            "dest_port": null,
            "dirs": false,
            "existing_only": false,
            "group": null,
            "link_dest": null,
            "links": null,
            "mode": "pull",
            "owner": null,
            "partial": false,
            "perms": null,
            "private_key": null,
            "recursive": null,
            "rsync_opts": [],
            "rsync_path": null,
            "rsync_timeout": 0,
            "set_remote_user": true,
            "src": "mysourceuser@mysourcehost:'/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopyprod'",
            "ssh_args": null,
            "ssh_connection_multiplexing": false,
            "times": null,
            "verify_host": false
        }
    },
    "item": "/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopyprod",
    "msg": "Warning: Permanently added 'mysourcehost' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.\r\n\nThis system is for the use by authorized users only. All data contained\non all systems is owned by the company and may be monitored, intercepted,\nrecorded, read, copied, or captured in any manner and disclosed in any\nmanner, by authorized company personnel. Users (authorized or unauthorized)\nhave no explicit or implicit expectation of privacy. Unauthorized or improper\nuse of this system may result in administrative, disciplinary action, civil\nand criminal penalties. Use of this system by any user, authorized or\nunauthorized, constitutes express consent to this monitoring, interception,\nrecording, reading, copying, or capturing and disclosure.\n\nIF YOU DO NOT CONSENT, LOG OFF NOW.\n\n##################################################################\n# *** This Server is using Centrify                          *** #\n# *** Remember to use your Active Directory account          *** #\n# ***    password when logging in                            *** #\n##################################################################\n\nrsync: change_dir \"/home/mysourceuser//'/web/playbooks/automation/misc\" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1658) [Receiver=3.1.2]\nrsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)\n",
    "rc": 23
}
```

From the output i got the concerned rsync command and tried to run it manually on my playbook host mydestuser@mydesthost and i get similar error:

```
"/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --copy-links --archive --rsh=/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L mysourceuser@mysourcehost:'/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopyprod' /web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopy/tmpfiles/500/"
```

Output:

```
bash: /bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --copy-links --archive --rsh=/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L mysourceuser@mysourcehost:'/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopyprod' /web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopy/tmpfiles/500/: No such file or directory
```

Upon suggestion from StackOverflow I quoted `--out-format` but I continue to get the same error. See snapshot of the error in the output below:

```
"/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --copy-links --archive --rsh=/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' mysourceuser@mysourcehost:'/tmp/myfolder' /tmp/myfolder1"
```

[image]

Can you please suggest?

Comment: What does that screenshot show? Please paste the text, not the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The playbook works for older versions of rsync.

With the latest version it started to fail as reported here.

Changed

```
 synchronize:
   src: "'{{ item }}'"
```

to

```
 synchronize:
   src: "{{ item }}"
```

and the error was gone issued resolved with the latest rsync.

Answer (score 2):

Your full command was this

> ```
> /bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --copy-links --archive --rsh=/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L mysourceuser@mysourcehost:'/web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopyprod' /web/playbooks/automation/misc/filecopy/tmpfiles/500/
> ```

You've omitted to quote arguments containing spaces, so when the shell parses the line it splits at those spaces, leading to syntax errors when `rsync` tries to understand the line.

Fix the `--rsh` parameter, which contains spaces, by changing it to this:

```
--rsh='/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'
```

Fix the `--out-format` parameter, which contains whitespace and shell special characters by changing it to this:

```
--out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L'
```

In a later example, you've put double quotes around the entire command, so the shell is trying to execute the entire command as a single entity. For example, in the first line the shell splits the line at spaces then executes the command `echo` with a parameter `hello`. In second line the shell sees the quoted string and *treats it as a single entity*; it then tries to execute the command called `echo hello` - not a command `echo` with a parameter `hello` but a command with a literal space character in the middle:

```
echo hello      # → hello
"echo hello"    # → -bash: echo hello: command not found
```

Rule: if a command or parameter contains a space or other special shell character and it's to be considered as a single item, it must be quoted.

Comment: despite quoting i get the same error. Updated the original post with the snapshot of output while trying your suggestion.